# KML LineString with mixed altitudeMode

Tags: kml

I'm using a LineString with altitudeMode set to "absolute" to draw a plane's flight path.  I have coordinates and an absolute altitude for each point along it's flight path.  That all draws fine.  But the last point of the path is when the plane lands.  I need to make sure that the LineString goes to the ground and doesn't end slightly above or below the ground due to differences in my GPS altitude reading versus Google Earth's ground elevation for the landing coordinate.  There isn't any way to switch altitude modes in the middle of a LineString is there?  How do I get the last point of my LineString to end up exactly at ground level?

Answer (score 0):

A [line geometry](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring) in KML can only have one altitude mode and for it to be above the ground it must either be **absolute** or **relativeToGround**.

If the altitude of the last point is at least at ground level or below it won't appear to be hanging in space if you're using absolute.

You could use a [MultiGeometry](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#multigeometry) with the line at absolute height and point clampedToGround. The line would show however it appears using Google's elevation data, but the placemark icon would be on the ground. Only alternative is to convert data to relative elevation and make sure the landing point is at 0, but it would be easier to just calculate the exact MSL elevation at the airport.

```
<Placemark>
  <MultiGeometry>
     <LineString>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>       
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>
          ....
          -77.03912,38.86485,75.5904        
        </coordinates>
     </LineString>
     <Point>
       <coordinates>
        -77.03912,38.86485
       </coordinates>
    </Point>
    </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```